# Chess game in C

Tags: beginner, c, game

I've never programmed in C before, but decided I wanted to try making Chess. Currently there's no way to check whether the game has ended. Was looking for critique for future projects.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// 1 pawn 2 rock 3 bishop 4 knight 5 queen 6 king
int currentTurn = 1;
int board[8][8] = {
    {2,4,3,5,6,3,4,2},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {2,4,3,5,6,3,4,2}
};
int blackWhite[8][8] = {
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
int moves[8][8];

int getValidMoves(int x, int y){
    int piece = board[y][x];
    int color = blackWhite[y][x];
    int canMove = 1;
    moves[y][x] = 2;
    if(x > 7 || x < 0 || y > 7 || y < 0)
        return 1;
    if(piece == 0){
        return 1;  
    }
    void towerMoves(){
         for(int dir = -1; dir < 2; dir+=2){
            int count = 1;
            while(1){
                if(x+(count*dir) <= 7 && x+(count*dir) >= 0){
                    if(board[y][x+(count*dir)] != 0){
                        if(blackWhite[y][x+(count*dir)] != color){
                            moves[y][x+(count*dir)] = 3;
                            canMove = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    }else{
                        moves[y][x+(count*dir)] = 1;
                        canMove = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            count = 1;
            while(1){
                if(y+(count*dir) <= 7 && y+(count*dir) >= 0){
                    if(board[y+(count*dir)][x] != 0){
                        if(blackWhite[y+(count*dir)][x] != color){
                            moves[y+(count*dir)][x] = 3;
                            canMove = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    }else{
                        moves[y+(count*dir)][x] = 1;
                        canMove = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    void runnerMove(){
        for(int xDir = -1; xDir < 2; xDir+=2){
            for(int yDir = -1; yDir < 2; yDir+=2){
                int count = 1;
                while(1){
                    if(x+(count*xDir) <= 7 && x+(count*xDir) >= 0 && y+(count*yDir) <= 7 && y+(count*yDir) >= 0){
                        if(board[y+(count*yDir)][x+(count*xDir)] != 0){
                            if(blackWhite[y+(count*yDir)][x+(count*xDir)] != color){
                                moves[y+(count*yDir)][x+(count*xDir)] = 3;
                                canMove = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                        }else{
                            moves[y+(count*yDir)][x+(count*xDir)] = 1;
                            canMove = 0;
                        }
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(piece == 1){
        if(color == 1){
            if(y == 6 && board[y-2][x] == 0){
                moves[y-2][x] = 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
            if(y-1 >= 0){
                if(board[y-1][x] == 0){
                    moves[y-1][x] = 1;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                if(x + 1 <= 7 && blackWhite[y-1][x+1] == 2 && board[y-1][x+1] != 0){
                    moves[y-1][x+1] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                if(x - 1 >= 0 && blackWhite[y-1][x-1] == 2 && board[y-1][x-1] != 0){
                    moves[y-1][x-1] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(y == 1 && board[y+2][x] == 0){
                moves[y+2][x] = 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
            if(y+1 <= 7){
               if(board[y+1][x] == 0){
                    moves[y+1][x] = 1;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                if(x + 1 <= 7 && blackWhite[y+1][x+1] == 1 && board[y+1][x+1] != 0){
                    moves[y+1][x+1] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                if(x - 1 >= 0 && blackWhite[y+1][x-1] == 1 && board[y+1][x-1] != 0){
                    moves[y+1][x-1] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    if(piece == 4){
        for(int i = -1; i < 2; i+=2){
            //TODO CLEAN THIS UP
            if(x+i <= 7 && x+i >= 0 && y+(2*i) >= 0 && y+(2*i) <= 7){
                moves[y+(2*i)][x+i] = blackWhite[y+(2*i)][x+i] == color && board[y+(2*i)][x+i] != 0 ? 0 : 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
            if(y+i <= 7 && y+i >= 0 && x+(2*i) >= 0 && x+(2*i) <= 7){
                moves[y+i][x+(2*i)] = blackWhite[y+i][x+(2*i)] == color && board[y+i][x+(2*i)] != 0 ? 0 : 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
            if(x-i <= 7 && x-i >= 0 && y+(2*i) >= 0 && y+(2*i) <= 7){
                moves[y+(2*i)][x-i] = blackWhite[y+(2*i)][x-i] == color && board[y+(2*i)][x-i] != 0 ? 0 : 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
            if(y-i <= 7 && y-i >= 0 && x+(2*i) >= 0 && x+(2*i) <= 7){
                moves[y-i][x+(2*i)] = blackWhite[y-i][x+(2*i)] == color && board[y-i][x+(2*i)] != 0 ? 0 : 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(piece == 3){
        runnerMove();
    }
    if(piece == 2){
        towerMoves();
    }
    if(piece == 5){
        towerMoves();
        runnerMove();
    }
    if(piece == 6){
        for(int xDir = -1; xDir < 2; xDir++){
            for(int yDir = -1; yDir < 2; yDir++){
                if(xDir+x <= 7 && xDir+x >= 0 && y+yDir >= 0 && yDir+y <= 7 && !(xDir == 0 && yDir == 0)){
                    if(board[yDir+y][xDir+x] != 0){
                        if(blackWhite[yDir+y][xDir+x] != color)
                            moves[yDir+y][xDir+x] = 3;
                            canMove = 0;
                    }else{
                        moves[yDir+y][xDir+x] = 1;
                        canMove = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return canMove;
}
void drawBoard(){
    printf("   ");
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        printf("%d: ",y+1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        printf("%d: ",x+1);
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
            if(board[x][y] != 0){
                printf("%d%d",board[x][y],blackWhite[x][y]);
            }else{
                printf("--");
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void drawMoves(){
    printf("   ");
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        printf("%d: ",y+1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        printf("%d: ",x+1);
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
            if(moves[x][y] == 0){
                printf("--");
            }else{
                printf("%d%d",moves[x][y],moves[x][y]);
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
char message[] = "White's turn";
int main(){
    while(1){
        system("@cls||clear");
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("   Chess in C\n");
        printf("----------------\n\n");
        printf("1.Start\n");
        printf("2.Rules\n");
        printf("3.Exit\n");
        printf("Input: ");
        int input;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        switch(input){
            case 1:
                goto start;
                break;
            case 2:
                system("@cls||clear");
                printf("-Every chess piece is displayed as a two digit number, example 42\n");
                printf("-The first number, 4 in this case indicates what chess piece it is\n");
                printf("-The second number, 2 indicates what color it is\n");
                printf("-When selecting a chess piece you select a cordinate where to origin is top left\n");
                printf("-Firstly you select a x position by typing a number from 1-8 and press enter\n");
                printf("-After that you select a y position from 1-8 and press enter\n");
                printf("-A menu will apear with availbe moves where a 22 is idicating of where your chess piece is and 11 for where it can move\n");
                printf("-If the move will result in a capture a 33 will be displayed instead of a 11\n");
                printf("-Follow the above steps on picking a cordinate to chose where the chess piece should be moved\n\n");
                printf("-Chess piece numbers are as follows: 1 pawn, 2 rook, 4 knight, 3 bishop, 5 queen, 6 king\n");
                printf("-Color numbers are as follows: 1 white, 2 black\n\n");
                scanf("%d", &input);
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    start:
    while(1){
        system("@cls||clear");
        if(currentTurn == 1){
            printf("White's turn\n\n");
        }else{
            printf("Black's turn\n\n");
        }
        drawBoard();
        int input[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            int c;
            scanf("%d", &c);
            input[i] = c - 1;
        }
        int x = input[0];
        int y = input[1];
        if(board[y][x] == 0)
            continue;
        if(blackWhite[y][x] != currentTurn)
            continue;
        if(getValidMoves(x,y) == 1)
            continue;
        system("@cls||clear");
        drawBoard();
        printf("\n");
        drawMoves();
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            int c;
            scanf("%d", &c);
            input[i] = c - 1;
        }
        if(moves[input[1]][input[0]] == 1 || moves[input[1]][input[0]] == 3){
            blackWhite[input[1]][input[0]] = blackWhite[y][x];
            board[input[1]][input[0]] = board[y][x];
            board[y][x] = 0;
            currentTurn = currentTurn == 1 ? 2 : 1;
        }
        for(int x_ = 0; x_ < 8; x_++){
            for(int y_ = 0; y_ < 8; y_++){
                moves[x_][y_] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `2 rock` guess `7 paper 8 scissors` have been lost due to `weather`?

Comment: Welcome to code review. What version of C are you compiling with because my C99 compiler doesn't allow the definition/declaration of functions within other functions. It seems like the code is doing this to get around parameter passage.

Answer (score 17):

## Use `enum`s to give names to numbers

It would be great if you could write `PAWN` instead of `1`, since it will be much clearer what you are doing in the code. The way to do this is to declare an `enum` for all possible chess piece types:

```
enum Type {
    NONE = 0,
    PAWN,
    ROOK,
    BISHOP,
    KNIGHT,
    QUEEN,
    KING,
};
```

I added `NONE` as well, it will be useful later to indicate tiles without a piece on them.
Once you have done that, instead of `if (piece == 1)`, you can write `if (piece == PAWN)`. Similarly, do this for the color of pieces:

```
enum Color {
    BLACK = 1,
    WHITE,
};
```

## Define a `struct` to combine chess piece type and color

Chess piece type and color go together, so it makes sense to make a struct out of this:

```
struct Piece {
    enum Type type;
    enum Color color;
};
```

Now we have that, we can combine the arrays `board` and `blackWhite` into one:

```
struct Piece board[8][8];
```

Now, instead of writing `color = blackWhite[y][x]`, you can write `color = board[y][x].color`.

Note, you could have made a single `enum` that listed both the black and white pieces (with names like `WHITE_ROOK`), and avoid having to create `struct Piece`, but indeed in your code it makes sense to have piece type and color as separate elements.

## Don't use nested functions

Nested functions are a GCC extension, but are not standard C. This means your code is not portable. Just move the functions `towerMoves()` and `runnerMove()` outside of `getValidMoves()`. Of course, now you need to pass `x` and `y` as arguments to these functions, and they should return the value of `canMove`.

## Use `switch`-statements where appropriate

Instead of having a long list of `if`-statements to check for each possible value of `piece` in `getValidMoves()`, write a `switch`-statement, like so:

```
switch (piece) {
case PAWN:
    ...
    break;
case ROOK:
    towerMoves();
    break;
case ...:
}
```

Not only does this improve the structure of your code, the compiler will actually check that you implemented a `case`-statement for each possible value of `piece`, and will warn you if you missed one.

## Move more code into separate functions

`getValidMoves()` is a very long function, even with the nested functions moved out of it. It makes sense to also make separate functions for getting the valid moves for each of the other chess piece types. This way, `getValidMoves()` will be much shorter and clearer to read.

## Be consistent when naming functions and variables

Decide whether you want to call it a rook or a tower, a bishop or a runner. Prefer using the official names for chess pieces.

You are also not consistent with other things; for example one functions is `towerMoves()`, another `runnerMove()` without the s. These functions are also just specializations of `getValidMoves()`. So be more consistent, and name the first two `getValidRookMoves()` and `getValidBishopMoves()`.

## Add whitespaces to make the structure of your code more clear

Add empty lines between functions, and between major sections within functions. This helps make the structure of your code more clear.

## Avoid using `system()`

Don't call `system()` for things you can just as well do within C itself. Using `system()` has a huge overhead, and it is not portable. To clear the screen, you can use ANSI escape codes, which will work in most terminals. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774983/clearing-the-screen-by-printing-a-character

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't know what enums was before this, but i'll 100% use them in the future. Again thank you, really good response :)

Answer (score 5):

Small review

**Put test first**

```
int getValidMoves(int x, int y){
    // Move test here
    if(x > 7 || x < 0 || y > 7 || y < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int piece = board[y][x];
    int color = blackWhite[y][x];
    int canMove = 1;
    moves[y][x] = 2;

    // Why test so late?  
    // Damage has been done access the above arrays with out-of-bounds indexes
    // if(x > 7 || x < 0 || y > 7 || y < 0)
    //    return 1;
```

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Aside from maybe 0 and 1, constants deserve identification.

```
#define MAX_RANK 7
#define MAX_COLUMN 7

// if(x > 7 || x < 0 || y > 7 || y < 0)
if(x > MAX_COLUMN || x < 0 || y > MAX_RANK || y < 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

or

```
#define RANK_N 8
#define COLUMN_N 8
if(x >= COLUMN_N || x < 0 || y >= RANK_N || y < 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid many duplicate calculations.
The code will be shorter and easy to read.

i.e. in towerMoves

```
void towerMoves(){
    for(int dir = -1; dir < 2; dir+=2){
        for(int tx = x+dir; tx>=0 && tx<=7; tx+=dir) {
            if(board[y][tx] != 0) {
                if(blackWhite[y][tx] != color) {
                    moves[y][tx] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                break;
            } else {
                moves[y][tx] = 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
        }
        for(int ty = y+dir; ty>=0 && ty<=7; ty+=dir) {
            if(board[ty][x] != 0){
                if(blackWhite[ty][x] != color){
                    moves[ty][x] = 3;
                    canMove = 0;
                }
                break;
            }else{
                moves[ty][x] = 1;
                canMove = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or with piece 4

```
void cleanUp(int y, int x) {
    if(x >= 0 && x <= 7 && y >= 0 && y <= 7){
        moves[y][x] = blackWhite[y][x] == color && board[y][x] != 0 ? 0 : 1;
        canMove = 0;
    }
}

if(piece == 4){
    for(int i = -1; i < 2; i+=2){
        cleanUp(y+2*i, x+i);
        cleanUp(y+i, x+2*i);
        cleanUp(y+2*i, x-i);
        cleanUp(y-i, x+2*i);
    }
}
```